# Forcefully bring android soft keyboard without any edit fields

Tags: android

I know we can bring the soft keyboard in android with any edit fields. I need to know whether it is possible to bring soft keyboard without any edit fields such as, on click of a button.

On click of a button, I need to bring the soft keyboard and monitor the key press events. Is there a way to bring soft keyboard on click of button?

Comment: did you got the answer ? is it working for your requirement ?

Answer (score 3):

well, the standard way of bringing up the soft keyboard is

```
InputMethodManager inputMgr = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMgr.toggleSoftInput(0, 0);
```

However, I've always used it to bring it up in conjunction with a `EditText` component. But I believe if you put that code in the click listener for the button, the keyboard should show up.

Comment: i tested above code, its not displaying keyboard. did you checked ?

Comment: @YugandharBabu at times it wasn't working for me too. but then, i put a sleep delay of 90ms before it. after that it's been working fairly consistently.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
InputMethodManager inputMgr = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMgr.showSoftInput(View youredittextobject, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED)
```

In above code the first argument is of the edittext object view that you need to pass for which you want the keyboard to show up